# Is it possible to listen for client connection to a server without pausing the whole code?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Recently, after being on the rim of getting bored of python, I decided to start learning socket programming in python. It went pretty well and i was able to establish TCP connections.

Then later i started adding GUI to the code to make it better. The problem with that is when i call the function s.listen(), the whole code pauses till the client connects, which is unacceptable for my GUI module (Pygame) as it causes lag and and ruins my event handling loops. So i was wondering if there is some other way of checking if a client is connecting to my server WITHOUT pausing the whole loop.

I did try Multi-threading:

```
#Wait for Connection then accept
Connection = False
def a():
    global Connection
    text = 'waiting for connection'
    while Connection==False:
        print(text)
        time.sleep(1)
        if text == 'waiting for connection...':
            text = 'waiting for connection'
        else:
            text = text+'.'
def b():
    global Connection
    s.listen(1)
    print("con")
    Connection=True

WaitScreen = threading.Thread(target=a)
WaitClient = threading.Thread(target=b)
WaitScreen.start()
WaitClient.start()
```

But to no avail.

Please inform me if you have any ideas. Stack Overflow here is my last resort. I've looked all over google and in every book i have. Maybe a function that just returns true when a client is trying to connect, instead of pausing the whole code. ANYTHING would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes  it is possible, you can use sockets and nonblocking socket options and select function: See Nonblocking sockets here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

Also David Beazley covers interesting concepts here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads work, even with blocking sockets.  In the example below, the server thread will block waiting for connections, and the client thread(s) will block waiting to receive data, but the main program will keep running:

```
#!python3.6
import threading
import socket
import time

def server():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('',8000))
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn,addr = s.accept() # will block here until client connects
        t = threading.Thread(target=client,args=(conn,addr),daemon=True)
        t.start()

def client(conn,addr):
    print(addr,'connected')
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024) # will block here waiting for data
        if not data:
            break
        print('got:',data)
    print(addr,'disconnected')
    conn.close()

server = threading.Thread(target=server,daemon=True)
server.start()
i = 0
# This will keep running
while True:
    print('-\|/'[i%4],end='\r',flush=True)
    time.sleep(.1)
    i += 1
```